# Javascript rewriting to DRY with loads of elements and arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dry

I'm having some problem with rewriting my code to the "DRY"-way. It's really messy right now because in this example I've even removed half of the arrays for this example.

---

The script works as the user selects a country from `#country-dropdown` with the country-codes as keys. The script fills a second dropdown with the corresponding array values.

So if i select "UK" in dropdown1, then it fills dropdown2 with the `uk` array. And right now everything works.

And it also changed text in a few site elements named #uk, #fr, #be etc.. with the selectedIndex in the dropdown2.

But the code is badly written and just looks plain ugly.

**Good to know:**

- All the number arrays are the same length, so I match them using the `selectedIndex`. Because If the user selects uk 4 it's matched with ru 38.

---

```
var uk = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12];
var fr = [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40];
var us = ["00", 0, 2, 4, 6, 8];
var ca = ["00", 0, 2, 4, 6, 8];
var de = [28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38];
var es = [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40];
var ru = [36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46];
var it = [34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44];
var be = [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40];

var countries = ["uk", "us", "fr", "it", "de", "au", "es", "jp"];
var selectedSize = $('#size').val();

//This function changes text in all the sites text elements named #uk, #fr, #de etc..
$('#size').change(function (e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
    {
        //var country = String(countries[i]);

        //console.log(uk[size.selectedIndex]);
        $("#uk").text(uk[size.selectedIndex]);
        $("#fr").text(fr[size.selectedIndex]);
        $("#de").text(de[size.selectedIndex]);
        $("#es").text(es[size.selectedIndex]);
        $("#ru").text(ru[size.selectedIndex]);
        $("#be").text(be[size.selectedIndex]);

    }

});


$('#country').change(function (e)
{
    $("#size").empty();
    var countrySize;

    var selectedCountry = $('#country').val();
    switch (selectedCountry)
    {
    case "uk":
        countrySize = uk;
        console.log(countrySize);
        break;
    case "fr":
        countrySize = fr;
        console.log(countrySize);
        break;
    case "de":
        countrySize = de;
        console.log(countrySize);
        break;
    case "es":
        countrySize = es;
        console.log(countrySize);
        break;
    case "ru":
        countrySize = ru;
        console.log(countrySize);
        break;
    case "be":
        countrySize = be;
        console.log(countrySize);
        break;
    }
    $.each(countrySize, function (val, text)
    {

        $('#size').append($('<option></option>').val(text).html(text))
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So my question is how i rewrite this to be more clean? I'm very thankful for hints/tips!

Comment: Sounds like a job for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Just use 2-dimensional associative array and loops. `countries["uk"] = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12];` and so on.

Comment: @Regent That will be `object`, not `array`. JS has no associative arrays

Comment: @hindmost that is correct, but it's more harder to understand for people. What is really worth to mention is that loop will be `for (var key in countries) { ... }`, not standard one.

Comment: @hindmost By definition, an associative array is a collection of key value pairs, where each key is unique and has its own value collection. Thus, you can consider a nested array, e.g. `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` an associative array, using an index (key) to get the desired collection.

Comment: @hindmost No, because each value would be a primitive type and not a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done in two steps. First, you should combine your country codes and size variables into a single object:

```
var countries = {
    "uk" : [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
    "fr" : [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40],
    "us" : ["00", 0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
    "ca" : ["00", 0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
    "de" : [28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38],
    "es" : [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40],
    "ru" : [36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46],
    "it" : [34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44],
    "be" : [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
};
```

Then, you should break those event handlers out into some reusable functions. You can also break out the menu-resetting code.

```
/**
 * Populate a menu, erasing whatever came before.
 *
 * @param select The menu to repopulate.
 * @param options An array of options to populate the menu with.
 */
function resetMenu(select, options) {
    console.debug(select, options);
    $(select).empty();
    $.each(options, function (val, text) {
        select.append($('<option></option>').val(text).html(text));
    });
}
/**
 * Change text in all the site's text elements with the names in countries.
 *
 * evt.data has two members:
 *     evt.data.menu is the menu to reference for the country.
 *     evt.data.countries is the countries object.
 *
 * this is the element that triggered the event handler: your $("#size")
 */
function changeSize(e) {
    var targetCountry = $(e.data.menu).val(),
        country;
    for (country in e.data.countries) {
        // The following if-check guards against modifications to Object.prototype
        if (e.data.countries.hasOwnProperty(country)) {
            if (country === targetCountry) {
                $('#' + country).text($(this).val());
            }
        }
    }
}
$("#size").change({
    "menu" : $("#country"),
    "countries" : countries
}, changeSize);

/**
 * Reset the size menu to reflect the selected country.
 *
 * As before, this is the menu that triggered the event.
 * But e.data is more complex:
 *     e.data.menu is the menu to change: $("#size")
 *     e.countries is the countries object.
 */
function changeCountry(e) {
    var selectedCountry = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,
        countrySize = e.data.countries[selectedCountry];
    resetMenu(e.data.menu, countrySize);
}
$("#country").change({
    "menu" : $("#size"),
    "countries" : countries
}, changeCountry);
```

I've set up [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/The_Spooniest/a14ucfLv/4/) where you can see this in action. There's also some menu-initialization code, since I needed some HTML to test this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an idea, I didn't really test this code. You can store all countries in an object, iterate that (`for (var key in countries)`) and use the country key to access the right element (`countries[selectedCountry]`).

```
var countries = {
    uk: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
    fr: [30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40]
    // ...
};

var selectedSize = $('#size').val();

//This function changes text in all the sites text elements named #uk, #fr, #de etc..
$('#size').change(function (e) {

    for (var key in countries) {
        $("#" + key).text(countries[key][size.selectedIndex]);
    }

});


$('#country').change(function (e) {
    $("#size").empty();
    var countrySize;

    var selectedCountry = $('#country').val();
    countrySize = countries[selectedCountry];

    $.each(countrySize, function (val, text) {
        $('#size').append($('<option></option>').val(text).html(text))
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```